# Unable to resolve identifier RBIE and RBIF, any guess?

Tags: c, pic, mplab, mplab-c18

trying to compile a code but keep giving build failed and checking red flags shows only Unable to resolve identifier in RBIE and RBIF.
below is the code i have im using it with a pic18f45k50 with a lcd and 4x4 keyboard try internet but only show the RBIE function and thats all and my teacher is not of much help so im on my own.

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <String.h>

#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC_HS
#pragma config WDT = OFF
#pragma config LVP = OFF
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

#define time 10
#define CD 0x01
#define RH 0x02
#define EMS 0x06
#define DC 0x0F
#define DSr 0x1C
#define DSl 0x18
#define FS 0x38
#define RAW1 0x80
#define RAW2 0xC0
#define E LATEbits.LATE0
#define RS LATEbits.LATE1
void settings(void);
void __interrupt() KB(void);
int keyboard(void);
void entrada(void);
void calculo(void);
void dataLCD(void);
void settingsLCD(unsigned char word);
void LCD(unsigned char data);
void writeLCD(unsigned char word);
int i, j, key, keys[4][4] = {
 {7, 8, 9, 15},
 {4, 5, 6, 14},
 {1, 2, 3, 13},
 {10, 0, 11, 12}
};
float numa, numb, operacion, igual, k=0, resultado;
char text[12], text2[12] = {"R= "};
void main(void){
 settings();
 while(1){
 }
}
void settings(void){
 OSCCON = 0X72;
 ADCON1 = 0x0F;
 TRISD = 0;
 LATD = 0;
 TRISE = 0;
 LATE = 0;
 TRISB = 0xF0;
 LATB = 0x0F;
 GIE = 1;
 RBIE = 1;
 RBIF = 0;
 settingsLCD(CD);
 settingsLCD(EMS);
 settingsLCD(DC);
 settingsLCD(FS);
 dataLCD();
}
void settingsLCD(unsigned char word){
 RS = 0;
 LCD(word);
}
void LCD(unsigned char data){
 E = 1; __delay_ms(time);
 LATD = data;
 __delay_ms(time);
 E = 0;
}
void __interrupt() KB(void){
 if (RBIF){
 if ((PORTB & 0xF0) != 0){
 k++;
 calculo();
 if (key == 11 || key == 10) {
 settingsLCD(RAW1 + 11);
 sprintf(text,"%.2f", resultado);
 for (i = 0; i <= strlen(text); i++){
 writeLCD(text[i]); // CAMBIO
 __delay_ms(time);
 }
 }
 LATB = 0xF;
 }
 RBIF = 0;
 }
}
int keyboard(void){
 LATB = 0x01;
 for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){ //CAMBIO
 if (PORTBbits.RB4){
 j = 0;
 break;
 } else if (PORTBbits.RB5){
 j = 1;
 break;
 } else if (PORTBbits.RB6){
 j = 2;
 break;
 }else if (PORTBbits.RB7){
 j = 3; break;
 }
 LATB = LATB << 1;
 }
 return keys[i][j]; //CAMBIO
}
void entrada(void){
 key = keyboard();
 if (k == 1){
 numa = key;
 } else if (k == 2){
 operacion = key;
 }else if (k == 3){
 numb = key;
 } else if (k == 4){
 igual = k;
 k= 0;
 }
}
void calculo(void){
 entrada();
 if(operacion == 15){
 resultado = numa / numb;
 } else if (operacion == 14){
 resultado = numa * numb;
 } else if (operacion == 13){
 resultado = numa - numb;
 } else if (operacion == 12){
 resultado = numa + numb;
 }
}
void dataLCD(void){
 settingsLCD(RAW1);
 for (i = 0; i<= strlen(text2); i++){
 writeLCD(text2[i]);
 __delay_ms(time);
 }}
void writeLCD(unsigned char word){
 RS = 1;
 LCD(word);
}
#pragma config DEBUG = ON
#pragma config F0SC = INT0SCI0
#pragma config WDTEN = OFF
#pragma config LVP = ON
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF
```

Comment: Did you check that the pic18f45k50 even has these registers? You cannot develop for an MCU without using its data sheet. ;-)

Comment: The data sheet can be found here: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/PIC18F45K50.  In general, when developing for MCU "X", as the first thing, Google "X data sheet" to get to know it.

Answer (score 1):

These bits are not implented in the PIC18F45k50 and they are not defined in the header. You had to change the name in your program:

`RBIF` -> `IOCIF`
`RBIE` -> `IOCIE`

Look into datasheet section 10.11:

> An input change on `PORTB<7:4>` or `PORTC<2:0>` sets
> flag bit, `IOCIF` of the `INTCON` register. The interrupt
> can be enabled/disabled by setting/clearing enable bit,
> `IOCIE` of the `INTCON` register. Pins must also be
> individually enabled with the `IOCB`/`IOCC` register.

Comment: Does that mean, the headers incorrectly declare these bits while they are not available on the MCU?

Comment: @SupportUkraine, it is clear enough. Those bits do not exist for *PIC18F45K50* while they do exist for its ancestor *PIC18F4550*. Therefore they are not defined in the relevant device's header file. So the OP has to change those bit names according to the naming conventions of that device. In this case RBIE has to be changed to IOCIE and RBIF has to be changed to IOCIF.